# Accounting for a variable that is not defined

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm a little stumped on how to account for a variable that is not defined (I'm not sure you even can at this point). I'm trying to work with the if else statement near the bottom of the below code (the line that's commented out).

The idea is, if the person requesting a song isn't an attendee or dog, the associated alert should run. As soon as the function is called, the interpreter recognizes that "guy" is not defined, which breaks everything. I could easily account for a variable that was UNDEFINED, but is it possible to account for one that is not defined? I've tried various things, but it seems like it's not actually possible.

Any ideas?

```
function Attendee(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var dan = new Attendee('Dan');
var christer = new Attendee('Christer');
var mooney = new Attendee('Mooney');

function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var murphy = new Dog('Murphy');
var lotty = new Dog('Lotty');
var willow = new Dog('Willow');


var songs = ['Vacationer - Farther', 'Tapes - Crowns', 'Lapalux - Straight Over My Head', 'Ben Khan - Youth', 'Touch Sensitive - Pizza Guy', 'Atu - The Duo', 'XO - The Light', 'Sohn - Artifice', 'Cambio Sun - Mad As They Come', 'Majical Cloudz - Your Eyes', 'Chet Faker - Talk is Cheap', 'Raffertie - Build Me Up', 'Oceaan - Candour', 'Oscar Key Sung - All I Could Do', 'Kenton Slash Demon - Harpe', 'Odesza - How Did I Get Here?', 'Tiger Tsunami - Antarctica', 'Gallant - Open Up'];

  var addSong = function(song, requester) {

    if (requester instanceof Attendee) {
      if (songs.indexOf(song) >= 0) {
        alert('Thanks, we\'ve already got that one!');
      } else {
        songs.push(song);
      }
    } else if (requester instanceof Dog) {
      alert(requester.name + ', you\'re a dog! You can\'t request a song!');
//    } else if () {
      alert('Who invited you?');
    }

  };

addSong('Vacationer - Farther', guy);
```

Comment: Where are you getting `guy` (as a variable name) from? No, there is no reason you should be able to do anything about invalid code. Of course, you can use `try catch`, but inside `addSong` for sure

Comment: Ok that's what I was wondering; since it's invalid code, nothing can be done.

I'll have to rethink how I'm identifying the song requesters. If I reference them by their name properties, I should be able pass in strings and have any string that isn't the name property of an existing object trigger the alert.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if a variable is defined *before* you reference it.

```
if (typeof guy !== "undefined") {
   addSong('Vacationer - Farther', guy);
} else {
   alert("Who invited you?");
}
```

If you want your `addSong` to be called even if `guy` is undefined.

```
   addSong('Vacationer - Farther', typeof guy !== 'undefined' && guy);
```

That will pass `false` as the requester if `guy` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Rather than checking if a variable is undefined, I wanted to be able to account for if it is NOT defined. I wanted to be able to pass in a variable that has never been declared at all, and have that alert run. Like Bergi said in the comment on the original post, my code is invalid since I'm referencing a variable that was never declared. All is lost! I have to rethink everything.